# Alphanumeric SQL Sorting to select Min and Max Values

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

Can someone help me get this result?

So my table values are for a table dbo.size are as follows:

```
Sc_Size
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I tried the following query:

```
select min(sc_size) as minsize,max(sc_size) as maxsize from dbo.Size
```

And this is the result I got:

```
minsize     maxsize
  1            9
```

but i want to get this as my result

```
minsize     maxsize
  1            10
```

so how do I get this result

Comment: I suspect sc_size a string?

Comment: The easiest, and probably best, solution would be to stop storing numbers as strings.

Comment: The problem with that is i have sizes like S, M, L and XL too

Answer (score 0):

The following will illustrate max of string vs max of integer

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Sc_Size] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1)
,(2)
,(3)
,(4)
,(5)
,(6)
,(7)
,(8)
,(9)
,(10)

Select MinString = min(sc_size)
      ,MaxString = max(sc_size)
      ,MinInt    = min(try_convert(int,sc_size))
      ,MaxInt    = max(try_convert(int,sc_size))
 from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
MinString   MaxString   MinInt  MaxInt
1           9           1       10
```